Does the trace of an operator commute with time derivatives of an operator?
I want to find the rate of entropy production in a quantum system using von Neumann entropy $$S = -tr{(\rho \ln{\rho})}$$ by taking it's time derivative. Can I take the derivative inside the trace or do these operators not commute (i.e. is $\frac{d}{dt}S = \frac{d}{dt}(-tr{(\rho \ln{\rho})}) = -tr{(\frac{d}{dt}(\rho \ln{\rho}))}$)?

The trace is a (infinite) sum. Limits and trace are exchangeable, if both sides exist. If  the left side is finite, $$\rho'(t)(1+ \log \rho(t))$$ must be trace summable. The diagonal  has to fall off faster than $1/n$ for a discrete spectrum.

Yes, you can, because the trace is nothing else than a sum and the derivative is a linear operator.

What are your assumptions? You probably assume something concerning differentiability and being trace class, what precisely?
